# Show / Hide tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Everyone
I have a problem and I have been searching the solution but could not find any. I am working on a tab bar based app. Problem is that I want to hide tab bar at first screen and then show it on all other screens that are being displayed after first screen.
Can anyone please give me the best solution for this problem?

Actual scenario is that I have a screen that is login screen. Now i dont want to show tab bar here as tab bar will be displayed only if the user is signed in. When user logs in, I want the tab bar to be displayed showing its contents.

Best Regards

Comment: see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627930/hide-the-tab-bar-when-pushing-a-view) with a great answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your Tab Bar Controller as your `rootController`, you can use `rootController.selectedIndex =0` for selecting 1st Tab bar Item, and     `rootController.selectedIndex =1;` and so forth.

As soon as that particular view loads, you can load the other views in an array, and then add it to the `rootController.selectedIndex` and `reloadInputViews` with animation.

**Edit:** (as per the comments)

So you have a tab bar controller, and you want to show the introduction and the login screen while starting the App. If login is successful, you want to present the tab bar controller ! This can be done with `ModalViewControllers`

1. In the `ViewDidLoad` of the view that loads up first, (it's your first tab by default), add

   ```
   //Declare Introduction Screen//

   IntroductionController *introductionController = [[IntroductionController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroductionController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   //Give a navigation screen for your introduction screen and set it to introduction screen
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:introductionController];

   navController.title = @"Introduction";
   navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
   [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
   ```
2. Now your introduction screen would load as soon as your first tab bar loads. But the loading is instantaneous, so it's not visible to the user's eye. Now reference your Login View Controller like `@class LoginController` and create an object `LoginViewController *lvc;`, and synthesize it. Now declare `LoginButton` and in the `IBAction`

   ```
   -(IBAction) loginAction: (id) sender{

    NSLog(@"I clicked Login");

    if (self.lvc ==nil){
       self.lvc = [[LoginController alloc] init ];

    }

    lvc.title = @"Login";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: self.lvc animated:YES];


    }
   ```
3. And in the `LoginViewController`, if Login is successful, just do

   ```
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   ```

Comment: Thanks Legolas for your reply but this is not what I need. My login screen will not be part of tab bar. Its a separate screen.

Comment: For Login? why dont you use a ModalViewController ?

Comment: And what if I have two screens, introduction and then login on which i dont want to show tab bar? :-( Introduction screen contains a button "Login". When we press this button, login screen appears. I dont want the tabbar on both of these screens. Your solution works for 1 screen. Thanks

Comment: Lol. Do this. Have introduction as your modal view controller. Now navigate to Login by `pushViewController`. If login is successful, just dismiss modal view controller, and both screen will be dismissed.

Comment: I think I have a good idea on what you are trying to do. If my comment (above) does not make sense, let me know, and i can modify answer for this.

Comment: its a tab bar based app. Can I use pushViewController?

Comment: @Aqueel. Of course you can. pushing view controller is an aspect of `navigationController`. Tab Bar Controllers have nothing to do with this, except hold views in each tab. You can control the views as you want.

Comment: Yes please modify your answer. Thanks

Comment: Okay before editing my answer, tell me if I am right with what I think you want - You have a tab bar controller with several tabs. You want to show an introduction of your app and login screen, and only after that you want to show tab bar controller (if login successful). Am i right with these ? (lets forget about hiding tabs as of now.)

Comment: Yes absolutely you are. But please note that I am not implementing navigation controller. So pushViewController will not do anything as I think. Am I right?

Comment: Sure. this is so nice of you really. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Woww that was amazing!! Legolas you saved me!! Thanks a lot!!! The solution works for me.

Comment: I hope this will help many many other developers who have been going through similar kind of problem.

Comment: It will. But you could also change the title to a more appropriate one, as now you know that this has nothing to do with hiding tab bars :P

Comment: ok suggest me one and I will change it if it is possible to change the title.

Comment: Click edit in your question and edit title to something like `Introduction and Login Screen in Tab Bar Controllers`

Answer (score -2):

create an outlet for the uitabbar, then declare it hidden in the first screen, then create a new void, NOT SENT SO IT DOESNT WORK in the first screen, make it say, lets say, hide. And inside hide, put code saying your uitabbar.hidden = YES; then, to make it work in the other view, write this in the viewDidLoad:

```
 [(//first view*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate //the void, in this case, hide];
```