# ModalView doesnt show up with tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am building an app that has a login screen that leads to a tabbar. I followed this example on how to push a modal view once you launch the app (as the "sign in" page) and then dismiss it.

Example --> [Show / Hide tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696893/show-hide-tab-bar/6696988#6696988)

From some reason, it's not really working - when I launch the app, I see the tabbar view with the two view controllers. no sign in page.

here is my code:

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstTab" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTab" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, secondNavController, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

}
```

My first tab (which is where I understand all this modal view business needs to happen)

.h

```
@interface FirstTab : UIViewController

@end
```

.m

//UPDATED CODE PER COMMENT BELOW

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
SignIn *loginview = [[SignIn alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignIn" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: loginview];
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 

}
```

And of course, I dismiss the modal view in the SignIn view controller, though I never get there as I mentioned.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
[[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

since first `viewController1` is your first tab, and `self.navigationController` might be nil.

In your custom view controller subclass called `SignIn` implement `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead if `init`.

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
              bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // init here
    }
}
```

Now when init/alloc it call either :

```
SignIn *loginview = [[SignIn alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignIn" bundle:nil];
```

if your interface is in a NIB file, or :

```
SignIn *loginview = [[SignIn alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

if there no NIB.

Also why putting it as a root view controller of any navigation controller ? unless you need to go deeper in some model data presentation, just present it directly :

```
// why ?
//UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc]
//                                      initWithRootViewController: loginview];
//self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; 
//[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];
```

Comment: can you try just `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];` ? if this not do it, the problem is elsewhere and you should check if `loginView` is correctly initialized

Comment: and of course `self.navigationController` is nil, because `viewController1` isn't root view controller of any navigation controller

Comment: Did not work as well....so frustrating...i will continue to check. Any help is still welcome!!

Comment: change `SignIn` `init` to implement `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead, this should do the trick, ask for more detail, if needed

Comment: or instead of calling `self = [super init];` in, call `self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Comment: no. I updated the code above to reflect what you said, but none of those options seem to work. I am sooo frustrated...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: no i didn't said you might initialize your view controller sending `initWithNibName:bundle`. Instead in your subclass you have to send that message to `super` in order for your view controller to be properly initialized

Comment: I am doing that...this is my init: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"First", @"First");
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemSearch tag:0];
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; 

    }
    return self;
}

Comment: hold on, i might have found something...stay tuned

Comment: that's right, and now when init/alloc the `SignIn` view controller, you should use `initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil` if there no related NIB, or `initWithNibName:@"SignIn" bundle:nil` if there is one

Comment: so I did this under the init method, and now it does load the signin page, but since I have added the "sign in" button programmatically, it doesnt show up. In fact, it doesnt execute the ViewDidLoad of my modal (the sign in). Is this right to init the first tab bar with with another nib?

Comment: another nib ? sorry I don't follow you. If `viewDidLoad` doesn't get called move your code in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: just tried this viewWillAppear and its not getting called....HELP!!!! I am losing it...

Comment: see the updated answer, try it, if it still doesn't work, I'm afraid the problem might be elsewhere, because apart from the few things I listed in my answer, what you do is correct

Comment: still nothing, bummer...thanks so much for the help. do you think my .h is ok? I didnt do anything there...maybe i should? no idea how to go about solving this...

Comment: unless you have some data to store in, or outlets to link with IB, all is ok in the .h, all properties we used are defined in superclass. And this shoudln't prevent the controller to be presented modally. Last proposal, try init/alloc `SignIn` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, and present it modally using : `[self.tabBarController present...]`

Comment: Did not work (doesnt load any view), but this is interesting...i am wondering if i should do all this in the AppDelegate anyway....

Comment: I think it is more correct to do this in app delegate, since you want the user to sign in when the app finish lauching.. sorry Tommy, in my point of view, there is something else wrong and your view controller and the try to present it modally is correct. If you can put the code online and, I could help you if you want, tell me, because this is the 15th comment, we should consider chatting ;)

Comment: had a look to the code, wasn't able to bring any view controller up. I writing a sample clean project based on what you want to do. I will provide a link soon.

Comment: [Test](http://www.freakishapps.com/Test.zip). sample project presenting a view controller modally at startup. Started from xcode tab bar app template. you can check there is nothing in SignIn.h. but I will recheck yours because I thinking of something

Comment: Two problems that I observed: 1. modal pops up slowly so you can see the back 2. I could not add any UI elements to the signin view controller - ViewDidLoad is not being executed.

Comment: have to go back home now. I'll be back soon

Comment: yes...any news? i am trying something new - have an if statement at the AppDelegate, either go to the login screen or straight to the tab bar, but then if I go to the home screen, not sure how to go back to the app delegate

Comment: when going to home screen, the app isn't terminated and go background, so when the user 'launch' it again, 'applicationDidFinishLauching' isn't reached

Comment: the second mistake you noted, is due to the init/alloc of SignIn VC, I made a mistake, I wrote `... = [[UIViewController alloc...`, replace that with the correct : `... = [[SignIn alloc...` so the viewDidLoad method will get called and you might be able to add UI elements

Comment: anything that can be done about (1)? (the delay in pop up modal?)

Comment: to be honest Tommy I didn't remark any delay (is that delay the time for the app to load ?)

Comment: No - I can see when I run your app the tab bar, the the sign in modal appears quickly

Answer (score 1):

You have to include this in your code,

```
yourModelController =[[Yourmodelcontroller alloc]init];

UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: yourModelController];


self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work out. I placed it in the first tab ViewDidLoad and nothing happens. Any ideas? See my updated code above.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered issues where modals don't like showing from `viewDidLoad`. Try adding your code to your `viewWillAppear` and it should show.