# Presenting login and registration view

Tags: iphone, xcode, view

I am working on an app whereby the user will have the login before using the services. How should I do about doing so, considering the user might register for an account through a UIButton on the login page, which will bring the user to registration view.

Can I use presentModalView to show the login view? If so, how do present I the registration view? Upon successful registration, the user will be auto logged in with the newly created account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Modal View Controller (Login View Controller) and set that inside a `UINavigationController`. If you use a Registration `UIButton` there, you will be able to navigate to the `RegistrationViewController` and based on the events happening, you can choose to `dismissModalViewController`.

A detailed explanation on what you are looking for...  is provided here - [Show / Hide tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696893/show-hide-tab-bar)  !!

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The other guy had almost the same scenario as mine.